# How to get 2nd highest salary of each employee in employee table which contains more than one entry in employee table

Tags: mysql

i am not asking about 2nd highest salary in employee table , i am asking about 2nd highest salary of each employee.

[click here to see employee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCeFG.png)

Comment: Why is a single person on multiple rows? If it was to keep historical data I'd understand but they all have the same timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inner query will return employees with their highest salary and then from out query those highest salaries will be filtered out 
so you will get the second highest salary

```
 SELECT MAX(T.salery),T.NAME FROM TABLE T
     INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(salery),NAME FROM TABLE GROUP BY NAME) TT 
      ON TT.NAME=T.NAME AND TT.SALERY!= T.SALERY 
       GROUP BY T.NAME;
```

example

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM payments;
+----+------------+---------+-------+
| id | date       | user_id | value |
+----+------------+---------+-------+
|  1 | 2016-06-22 |       1 |    10 |
|  2 | 2016-06-22 |       3 |    15 |
|  3 | 2016-06-22 |       4 |    20 |
|  4 | 2016-06-23 |       2 |   100 |
|  5 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |   150 |
|  6 | 2016-06-23 |       2 |   340 |
+----+------------+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select max(value),user_id from payments group by user_id;
+------------+---------+
| max(value) | user_id |
+------------+---------+
|        150 |       1 |
|        340 |       2 |
|         15 |       3 |
|         20 |       4 |
+------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select max(T.value),TT.user_id from payments T inner join (select max(value) as val,user_id from payments group by user_id) TT on T.value!=TT.val and T.user_id=TT.user_id group by T.user_id;;
+--------------+---------+
| max(T.value) | user_id |
+--------------+---------+
|           10 |       1 |
|          100 |       2 |
+--------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a very quick solution could be like this:

```
 SELECT MAX(column) FROM table WHERE column < (SELECT MAX(column) FROM table)
```

Hope it helps-

Comment: OP said "each employee" though, this will only return one row ever. I still think his database design makes no sense though.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen you are right, in fact the table should be normalized but here it is not the case...

Comment: this is useless he want to get it for each employee